# EError in Update SQL syntax

Tags: java, mysql, sql-update

Prompt user to enter registered no. to update.
Here is my code:

```
System.out.println("Enter Reg no to update: ");
    int Uregno = in.nextInt();
    String sqlUpdate = "UPDATE vehicle" + "SET name=?" + "ic=?" + "plate=?" + "color=?" + "year=?" + "make=?" + "model=?" + "capacity=?" + "type=?" + "maxload=?"+ "WHERE regno=?"+Uregno;
```

I keep getting this error

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version....."

The SQL query looks like this in myphpadmin:
    UPDATE `vehicle` SET `regno`=[value-1],`name`=[value-2],`ic`=[value-3],`plate`=[value-4],`color`=[value-5],`year`=[value-6],`make`=[value-7],`model`=[value-8],`capacity`=[value-9],`type`=[value-10],`maxload`=[value-11] WHERE 1

I have set the regno to an auto-increment key, is it ok to exclude it in the query?

Comment: It's probably the lack of spaces between words in your query, like `vehicle` and `SET`

Comment: You are missing spaces and commas between each element of your query, space between `vehicle` and `SET` and commas between each of the assignments

Comment: and space before `WHERE` also

Comment: Also please edit your question to remove the `php` tag

Comment: you fogot comma `,` after field that you set.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your query is correct:

```
String sqlUpdate = "UPDATE vehicle " + "SET name=?, " + "ic=?, " + "plate=?, " + "color=?, " + "year=?, " + "make=?, " + "model=?, " + "capacity=?, " + "type=?, " + "maxload=? "+ "WHERE regno=?"+Uregno;
```

and make sure you pass the correct parameters.

Comment: Thx for your reply, I'm still getting errors... I've done some editing, can you read my post again

Comment: @Michael how are you passing the values?

Comment: I've changed my mind and i want to do something like this:   "String sql = "update student set age=" + age +", gender='"
+ gender +"' where name='" + name +"'"; "   But why are there so many ' symbol... its very confusing

Comment: @Michael please edit your question, add the new task and the code you have been using to pass the parameters as well as the query.

Answer (score 0):

If you did not concatenate each part of the statement you could easily find the errors:

```
String sqlUpdate = 
  "UPDATE vehicle SET name=?, ic=?, plate=?, color=?, year=?, make=?, model=?, capacity=?, type=?, maxload=? WHERE regno=?"
```

Also that final concatenation:

```
+Uregno
```

would give syntax error. 
If `Uregno` is the value you want to pass for the `WHERE` parameter, then you should pass it just like all the other parameters with the `?` placeholders (with a `PreparedStatement`).
Or remove the final `?` and pass it like this:

```
String sqlUpdate = 
  "UPDATE vehicle SET name=?, ic=?, plate=?, color=?, year=?, make=?, model=?, capacity=?, type=?, maxload=? WHERE regno=" + Uregno;
```

Comment: I've tried every solution but still getting errors... is it because regno is a primary key?

Comment: `regno` is the id of the row that you want to update. If it is an integer number that exists in the table then the code above should run with no errors if you pass all the other parameters correctly and you have not misspelled the table name or any column name.

Comment: I've checked many times, the numbers do exist in the table and all parameters are correct. Everything just seems fine. But it's still error.

Comment: "PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlUpdate);" Is there any error in this line?

Comment: If the connection is valid then this like is ok. Then you need to pass all the parameters.

Comment: The last query you posted is trying to set a value to `regno`. You must not change the value of the primary key. Remove it.

Comment: Did you mean the query in myphpadmind "SET regno=[value-1]"? If yes, I already removed it in my code. The regno only appears after "WHERE " in my code.

Comment: Yes I meant that query.

Comment: Thanks for your patience... I still got it wrong somehow. I have no idea what's wrong with it.

Comment: If you have not any specific error message then your problem is not reproducable. If you have corrected the update statement like the above code then there is no syntax error. So the error must be related to the rest of your code or maybe with the structure of your table.